# How to check for non empty list in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to learn functional programming with Ocaml and I want to implement a function, which returns the sum of the elements in a list. I want to do it using a while loop, but I can't think of a way to write the check.

I imagined something like this

```
let sum_it (xs: int list) = 
   let j = ref 1 in
   let add x y = x+y in
   while xs <> [] do
      j := add !j hd ; 
      xs = tl done ;
   !j ;;
```

but now it fails with the `j := add !j hd ;`

*Error: This expression has type 'a list -> 'a
but an expression was expected of type int*

Comment: I think you'll want to use recursion and pattern matching instead for this, but the not equal operator is `<>`. The available operators are all listed in the API documentation. See https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#VAL(%3C%3E)

Comment: Please don't alter the question to ask something completely different. The code you provide also does not produce the error you claim it does. Make sure you are providing a [mcve]. Though it seems like what you really want is mentoring, and SO really isn't appropriate for that.

Comment: Keep in mind that `xs` is an immutable list. Your `while` loop can't change it, so it either never runs, or runs infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

The OCaml way to analyze the shape of a value is to use pattern matching:

```ml
match list with
| [] -> ... (* 1 *)
| a :: q -> ... (* 2 *)
```

Compared to a language with only conditionals (like C), the advantage of pattern matching is that it directly associate a check to see if a value has a certain shape with the action to run for values of that shape. Combined with the possibility to check if a pattern matching covers all case, this decrease considerably the room for mistakes.

For instance, with

```
| [] -> ... (* 1 *)
```

the action `1` on the right hand side of `->` is only run if the matched list `list` is empty whereas the second action

```
| a :: q -> ... (* 2 *)
```

is only run if the list has the shape `a :: q` for some `a` and `q`. Moreover, this second action can use the value `a` of the head of the list and the value `q` of the tail of the list directly in its body. For instance

```
| a :: q -> a + List.length q
```

sums the first element of the list `list` with the length of its tail.

P.S: The use of `while` loop for simple recursive function is not optimal. The idiomatic OCaml way is to define a recursive function. Indeed, a `while` loop may have a very complex flow of data. Contrarily, a pure recursive function will have much more explicit and often simpler flow of data.